# How to copy a table with no records?

Tags: sql, h2

I'm using H2 database. I tried the following SQL, but the records are also copied:

```
"CREATE TABLE test_tmp AS SELECT * FROM test"
```

I also tried this sql:

```
"CREATE TABLE test_tmp AS SELECT * FROM test WITH NO DATA",
```

But I got an syntax error exception. So do you know how to copy a table with no records?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Create table testtmp as select * from test where 1=0
```

Comment: This will not create table metadata like indexes constrains fields attributes and so.

Answer (score 2):

```
    SELECT * INTO test_tmp FROM test WHERE 1=2
```